# Using Flex Builder with source control

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, version-control

When setting up a source control repository for a Flex Builder workspace, what do you consider to be worth checking in? Do you exclude the workspace .metadata folder but keep the .project and other project specific files? Keep both? Throw away both? Is there a guideline you use to decide which is worth holding onto or do you do it out of practical experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check in the source directoy and the binary directory; nothing else.  I set up my Flex Builder project to use a linked directory as my primary source; which keeps the code and repository independent of any project specific settings.

I have known people who check in all the project files.  This makes it relatively easy to check out and then set up a new project; as you can import the project folder very easily into Flex Builder.

I can't say one is better than the other, though.  It depends what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

We check in the source files but not the binaries or settings files (e.g., .actionScriptProperties, .flexLibProperties, nothing in bin-debug, nothing in target directory). We build and deploy with Maven.

Comment: This is what I do as well, additionally we use maven to generate the flex project files, as explained here: http://maven.servebox.org/sites/maven-flex-plugin/flex-plugin/